# How to use iteration data with newman

Tags: database, rest, postman, newman

I have a collection in **Postman** which loads "payload objects" from a json file and want to make it run in **newman** from command like.

**POST request**

- **Body:** of POST request I have got `{{jsonBody}}`
- **Pre-request Script:** logically `pm.globals.set("jsonBody", JSON.stringify(pm.iterationData.toObject()));`

and a `file.json` file with this kind of "objects":

```
[
    {
    "data": {
        "propert1": 24,
        "property2": "24__DDL_VXS",
        ...
    },
        {
    "data": {
        "propert1": 28,
        "property2": "28__HDL_VDS",
        ...
    }
...
]
```

**Works** like a charm in **Postman**.

Here is what I'm trying to run in cmd.

```
newman run \
-d file.json  \
--global-var access_token=$TOK4EN \
--folder '/vlanspost' \
postman/postman_collection_v2.json
```

Based on the results I am getting - it looks like that **newman** is not **resolving** flag:

`-d, --iteration-data <path>           Specify a data file to use for iterations (either JSON or CSV)`

and simply passes as payload literally this string from **Body** section: `{{jsonBody}}`

Anyone has got the same issue ?

Thx

Comment: I think newman doesn't know where to file `file.json`. Could you try add full path_to_file?

Comment: Hi @lucasnguyen17, I have tried to provide a full path but got the same result.

Comment: I am thinking whether the file exported from Postman might be in some incorrect format? @lucasnguyen17

Comment: I figured that payload is actually resolved from --iteration-data but newman must be passing this payload in some malformed form - because I have used --verbose with newman and copy/paste the very same payload via curl and httpie (both work as charm) but when using newman - I get `500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR` so Flask will not even process request and werkzeug will automatically throw INTERNAL SERVER ERROR 500 @lucasnguyen17

Comment: SO I fouud how `newman` sends payload.
1. When I debug my Flask app in PyCharm and catching request payload from `newmam`- `request.get_json()` does not exist - and it must exist (even Postman sends data in json format)
2. when using postman/curl/httpie `request.get_json()` simply exists 

So the Postman export must be somehow wrong. I am suspecting this line in **prerequest** section of exported collection:
`"type": "text/javascript"`

@lucasnguyen17

Answer (score 1):

I did that way and it worked.

1. Put collection and data file into a same directory. For example:

```
C:\USERS\DUNGUYEN\DESKTOP\SO
        ---- file.json
        \___ SO.postman_collection.json
```

2. From this `folder`, make `newman` command.

```
newman run .\SO.postman_collection.json -d .\file.json --folder 'vlanspost'
```

3. This is the result:

[image]